# Relation between crush and krushiti

Tags: etymology

Do the English verb "crush" and the Old Slavonic verb крушити (krushiti) "to break, to destroy" [where ити (iti) is a verb ending] have somehow relation with themself. Internet sources are scanty:  
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C 
https://lexicography.online/etymology/vasmer/%D0%BA/%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: [probably not](https://www.etymonline.com/word/crush): "from Old French cruissir (Modern French écraser), variant of croissir "to gnash (teeth), crash, smash, break," which is perhaps from Frankish *krostjan "to gnash" (cognates: Gothic kriustan, Old Swedish krysta "to gnash")." If you can find the etymology of 'крушити' we could confirm.

Comment: @Mitch I want to add, that Old Slavonic also has the word укрух (ukruh) "fragment", where у(u) is a prefix and that Old Slavonic has the standart alternation h ->s->sh. In theory the word "ukruh" in the plural should be written as "ukrusi". Also I know that two French letters "oi" are pronounced as "ua"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the etymology of 'крушити' is outside ELU's scope.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  Slavonic etymology is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

According to the *Online Etymological Dictionary*, the ultimate etymology of [*crash*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/crush#etymonline_v_416) beyond Old French *cruissir*, ‘gnash (teeth), crash, smash, break’ is not certain, but may well be from an originally Germanic root from the Frankish superstrate, **krostjan*, cognate to Goth  (kriustan), ‘to gnash, break in pieces’, OSwed *krysta*, ‘to gnash, crackle’.

Starting from the end, the *ʃ (š)* in common with your Slavonic word is not original even in French, but sometimes occurs when an original French *s* is borrowed into English. Compare [*push*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/push#etymonline_v_2911), OF *poulser* (ModF *pousser*), from Lat *pulsare*, ‘to beat, strike, push’; [*brush*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/brush#etymonline_v_17185), OF *broisse, broce*; [*quash*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/quash#etymonline_v_3161), OF *quasser, casser* ‘to annul, declare void’ and/or Late Lat *quassare, cassare*, from *cassus*, ‘null, void, empty’.

If the connection to Gothic and Old Swedish is correct, then the reconstructed Proto-Germanic root is [**krus-*, **kriustan-*, **krusta-z*](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/etymology.cgi?single=1&basename=%2Fdata%2Fie%2Fgermet&text_number=++1157&root=config), which in turn derives from a PIE root **graus-*, **grauks-*.

Only in the Germanic descendents of this root does the initial consonant devoice: in Slavic languages the root is reconstructed as [**grūxātī*, **grūšītī*, **grūšā*](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/etymology.cgi?single=1&basename=%2Fdata%2Fie%2Fgermet&text_number=++1157&root=config) and in Baltic as the verbal root [**grukš-ē̂-*](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/etymology.cgi?single=1&basename=%2Fdata%2Fie%2Fgermet&text_number=++1157&root=config), more distantly Lat *ingruo*, ‘attack, assail’.

In a Slavic word, then, one would expect the voiced consonant to be retained. Without initial and final consonant, there isn’t much left to suggest that крушити and *crash* are even distant cognates.

This does, however, suggest [*грохнуться*](https://glosbe.com/ru/en/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) (grokhnut'sya), ‘fall, crash’  as a distant cousin of *crash* by way of a common PIE root, but not Old Slavonic крушити (krushiti).

Comment: To complete the picture, Derksen and Beekes (Brill’s etymological dictionaries for Slavic and Greek, respectively) as well as [LIV²](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexikon_der_indogermanischen_Verben) both take OCS _(sъ-)krušiti_ pretty directly back to a PIE root _*kreu̯s-_ ‘stoßen’, being cognate with Gk. _κρούω_ ‘beat, strike, stamp, knock’, both from an o-grade: the Slavic form from a causative _*krou̯s-éi̯e-_ and the Greek from a _-i̯e/o-_ present _*króu̯s-i̯e-_. (De Vaan connects Lat. _(in)gruō_ with a different root, _*gʰreu̯h₁-_ ‘rush’.)

Comment: The characters for the one word () can't be shown on my device. If possible, can you use other characters for this?

Comment: @Laurel: The transcription is in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Your linked page gives:

> krushít' noun.
> krushíti, verb. -Slavic.
>
> Incompletative "-kroushiti"
>
> from the Greek, συντρίβειν, θραύειν, κρούειν, [to crush]. i.e., syntrívein, thrávein, **kroúein**,
>
> [Compare] krúshiti «kroshit'», Slovenian. krúšiti, Czech. krušiti, Polish. kruszyć, Byeloruss. krušić.
>
> Reference: krukh, krokhá; See Berneker 1, 628 i sl.; Meyye, MSL 14, 363.
>
> For "crush" the OED, **the entry for which was last updated in 1893,** gives
>
> Etymology: apparently < Old French croissir, croisir, sometimes cruis(s)ir, rarely crusir, croussir, to gnash (the teeth), to make a crashing or cracking noise, to crash, crack, smash, break; in Cotgrave, 1611, ‘to cracke, or crash, or crackle, as wood thats readie to breake’; = Catalan croxir, Spanish cruxir, crujir to crackle, to rustle, Italian †croscere, crosciare to crackle, crash, clatter; ‘also to squease, to crush, or squash’ (Florio); medieval Latin cruscire to crackle (Du Cange). **The Romanic word is apparently of German origin: see Diez and Mackel, and compare Middle High German krosen, krösen to gnash with the teeth, make a crackling noise, bruise or crush with a crackling sound, crash, craunch, for which Hildebrand infers an Old High German chrosôn, chrosian.**
>
> The notion of noise present in the foreign words appears also in early uses of cruss , crussh , but is practically absent from later use, being now expressed by crash v.

Although the Greek κρούειν, [to crush]. i.e., kroúein, is not mentioned, I think that there is probably a good chance that the two words are related.